# How to dynamically add elements to reactor hot flux from another method?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, flux, rsocket

I have a data source service, which takes an observer as a parameter.

```
void subscribe(Consumer onEventConsumer);
```

I want to use flux as a response stream for RSocket.
How can I do this?
As I see it now, it should be something like

```
Flux<T> controllerMethod(RequestMessage mgs) {
   var flux = Flux.empty();
   dataSource.subscribe(event -> flux.push(event));
   return flux;
}
```

But I have big doubts that it's a proper solution, and I'm new in the reactive approach, I don't know what methods I should use here?

Answer (score 3):

As Simon already pointed out, this is what you use `Flux.create` for.

Take a look at the [Getting Started Guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing) on [projectreactor.io](https://projectreactor.io/).

In short, you register a custom listener inside the lambda of the `create` method:

```
Flux<String> bridge = Flux.create(sink -> {
    myEventProcessor.register( 
      new MyEventListener<String>() { 

        public void onDataChunk(List<String> chunk) {
          for(String s : chunk) {
            sink.next(s); 
          }
        }

        public void processComplete() {
            sink.complete(); 
        }
    });
});
```

What you want to do is to pass the incoming elements on to a [FluxSink](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/FluxSink.html), which will then publish those elements on the Flux.

Answer (score 0):

this is a typical use case of Flux.create. you register an obsereer from inside the create lambda, which will pass the data it receives down to the provided FluxSink

Comment: Is your suggestion valid in the case where we want to add an element to the flux following an Http call ? i.e a client sends a POST request to an endpoint with the message he wants to publish. thank you

Comment: that sounds like a completely different use case. in OP's case, a single `Flux` needed to reflect a single listener established by calling (as I understand non-reactive) `subscriber(Consumer)`. in your case it sounds like multiple calls to that endpoint should all publish to the same `Flux`. Look into the `Sinks` API in 3.4.0 for that.

Comment: That's exactly what I did! It's SO well-made and seems to cover the Safe production from multiple threads. Thank you Simon.