# I want to add objects in Flux dynamically

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am very new to reactive programming in Spring WebFlux. Kindly excuse me for my ignorance here.

The below code is not adding the object EyeCare to the Flux eyeCares.
I read about `Flux.create`, `Flux.generate` [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing) that seem to be used to create Flux also I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65869403/4068218)

```
private Flux<EyeCare> populateFakeData(Locale locale, int count){
    Flux<EyeCare>  eyeCares = Flux.empty();
    for(int i=0; i< count; i++){               
        eyeCares.concatWithValues(fakeDataService.generateEyeCare(locale));
    }
    return eyeCares;
}
```

1. Are `Flux.create` or `Flux.generate` the way I need to take to solve this?
2. If yes then from where **myEventProcessor** came in the [code snipped](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing)
3. How can I bring in `Flux.create` or `Flux.generate` instead of `eyeCares.concatWithValues`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `Flux::generate` pretty easily.

```
private Flux<EyeCare> populateFakeData(Locale locale, int count){
    return Flux.generate(()->new AtomicInteger(count), (state, sink) -> {
        if (state.getAndDecrement() > 0 ) {
            sink.next(generateEyeCare(locale));
        } else {
            sink.complete();
        }
        return state;
    });
}
```

Comment: Just to add - `Flux.generate()` (as used here) is almost always preferable over create if you can use it, since it emits items "one by one" on demand based on request rate), meaning your subscriber shouldn't be swamped with more than it can handle.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, you can use `range` and `map`:

```java
private Flux<EyeCare> populateFakeData(Locale locale, int count){
    return Flux.range(1, count)
            .map(i -> fakeDataService.generateEyeCare(locale));
}
```